# How to send requestparam with Multipart file using retrofit?

Tags: android, spring-boot, kotlin, retrofit

I have this endpoint in spring boot.

```
    @PostMapping("/uploadPhoto")
    public String uploadPhoto(@RequestParam String email, @RequestPart(name = "img") MultipartFile file) {
        studentService.updateImageLink(email, file);
        return "OK";
    }
```

And Service endpoint in retrofit

```
    @POST("uploadPhoto")
    @Multipart
    suspend fun uploadPhoto(@Part("email") email: String, @Part img: MultipartBody.Part): String
```

Here how I am sending my file

```
val file = File(getPath(selectedImage!!));
            val requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            val fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img", file.name, requestBody);
            viewModel.uploadPhoto("bekjan.omirzak98@gmail.com", fileToUpload);
```

I am getting retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 . Is this problem form server-side or client-side?

Comment: isn't @RequestParam for a query parameter ? On the retrofit side I would have expected @Query("email") not @Part("email"). I might be wrong tho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send your primitive type arguments as a `RequestBody` instead of String.

```
@Multipart
@POST("uploadPhoto")
Call<Void> uploadPhoto(@Part("email") RequestBody email, 
                       @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

and in your request method you should insert your parameters like the following:

```
public void uploadProfileImage(String email, File imageFile) {
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), imageFile);

    MultipartBody.Part imageBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFile.getName(), requestFile);

    RequestBody emailBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), email);

    getRetrofitClient().uploadPhoto(emailBody, imageBody);
}
```

Comment: Congrats. Then you can mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote it, I don't have enough reputations. Sorry for that.